# how to chage the button title dynamically in iphone

Tags: iphone

I had one requirement in that need to change the button title with existing title
for example button title is "Others", in run time need to change "Others(3)". need to know how to fit the integer value (3) with button title.

Pleas help on this 
Here is the button source code.

```
 mOthersBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [mOthersBtn setTitle:@"Others" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [mOthersBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(mOthersClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        mOthersBtn.frame = CGRectMake(20, 320, 280, 25);
        [self.view addSubview:mOthersBtn];
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Do you want to integrate the number of clicks on that button ?? what is 3?

Comment: just re-set the title of the button? [mOthersBtn setTitle:@"Others (3)" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Answer (score 3):

Just use stringWithFormat:

```
NSInteger count = 3;
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Others (%i)", count] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: (Also, read up on string formats in general, they are quite useful)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Run time text here"];


[button setTitle: str forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: @"Run time text here" means your string containing your runtime text. there you can place your string.
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",StrRunTimeText];

Answer (score -1):

NSInteger c = 2;
[button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Others (%i)", c] forState:UIControlStateNormal];